# How Can I Have a BeforCancel Event for TFieldDataLink?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7

I wrote a dbedit and a Listbox as a subcomponent, depend on dbedit.text, listbox appear and show some information. I want hide listbox if database canceled.

Comment: How does a `TFieldDataLink` get cancelled? Can you define "cancel", so we can perhaps understand what you're trying to do? I understand that an insert or edit to a table can be cancelled, but what exactly would be cancelled on a field itself?

Comment: receive by linked dataset.

Comment: What do you mean with "canceled"? "Cancel" after "Edit" or "Insert" of a record? Then you can probably use "BeforeCancel" or "AfterCancel" of the used TDataSet.

Comment: @Andreas Cancel after Insert. I tried write a class based on 'TFieldDataLink' with 'TDataSetNotifyEvent' property for creating 'BeforCancel' but I don't know how do I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to get this notification.

The closest you can get is the [`TFieldDataLink.DataEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TFieldDataLink.DataEvent), but before cancellation of an operation is not one of the supported notification events, according to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TFieldDataLink.DataEvent) (reformatted slightly for readability here):

```
Data event                       Info                        Method called  
----------                       -----                       -------------
deFieldChange | deRecordChange   The field that changed      RecordChanged 
deDataSetChange                  Current index into the      DataSetChanged 
                                 record buffer 
deDataSetScroll                  Current index into the      DataSetScrolled 
                                 record buffer 
deLayoutChange                   Current index into the      LayoutChanged 
                                 record buffer 
deUpdateRecord                   UpdateRecord 
deUpdateState                    EditingChanged or 
                                 ActiveChanged 
deCheckBrowseMode                CheckBrowseMode 
deFocusControl                   FocusControl
```

There is also no event available in the ancestor of the class, [`TDataLink`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataLink), again according to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataLink).